# VTK efficiency of vtkRenderWindow::GetZbufferData and vtkWindowToImageFilter::Update

Tags: vtk

I have a snippet that converts vtk (off screen) rendering to 1)Point cloud; 2)Color image. The implementation is correct, it just the speed/efficiency is an issue.

At the beginning of every iteration, I update my rendering by calling:

```
renderWin->Render ();
```

For point cloud, I get the depth using following line and then convert it to point cloud (code not posted).

```
float *depth = new float[width * height];
renderWin->GetZbufferData (0, 0, width - 1, height - 1, &(depth[0]));
```

For color image, I use `vtkWindowToImageFilter` to get current color rendered image:

```
windowToImageFilter->Modified();    // Must have this to get updated rendered image
windowToImageFilter->Update();  // this line takes a lot of time
render_img_vtk = windowToImageFilter->GetOutput();
```

Above program is run in the same thread sequentially. The renderWindow size is about 1000x1000. There is not a lot of polydata needs to be rendered. VTK was compiled with OpenGL2 support.

**Issue:**
This code only runs about 15-20Hz, when I disabled/comment the `windowToImageFilter` part (`vtkWindowToImageFilter::Update()` takes a lot of time), the framerate goes to about 30Hz.
When I disabled/comment `vtkRenderWindow::GetZbufferData`, it goes up to 50Hz (which is how fast I call my loop and update the rendering).

I had a quick look of the VTK source file of these two function, I see it copy data using GL command. I am not sure how can I speed this up.

**Update:**
After some search, I found that the `glReadPixels` function called in the `GetZbufferData` causes delay as it try to synchronize the data. Please see this post: [OpenGL read pixels faster than glReadPixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127751/opengl-read-pixels-faster-than-glreadpixels).
In this post, it is suggested that PBO should be used. VTK has a class `vtkPixelBufferObject` but no example can be found for using it to avoid blocking the pipeline when do `glReadPixels()`

So how can I do this within the VTK pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is just about the GetZbufferData portion.

`vtkOpenGLRenderWindow` already uses `glReadPixels` with little overhead from what I can tell. [here](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx#L1483)

What happens after that I believe can introduce overhead. Main thing to note is that `vtkOpenGLRenderWindow` has 3 method overloads for `GetZbufferData`. You are using the method overload with the same signature as the one used in `vtkWindowToImageFilter` [here](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/Core/vtkWindowToImageFilter.cxx#L534)

I believe you are copying that part of the implementation in `vtkWindowToImageFilter`, which makes total sense. What do you do with float pointer `depthBuffer` after you get it? Looking at the `vtkWindowToImageFilter` implementation, I see that they have a for loop that calls `memcpy` [here](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/Core/vtkWindowToImageFilter.cxx#L542). I believe their `memcpy` has to be in a for loop in order to deal with spacing, because of the variables `inIncrY` and `outIncrY`. For your situation you should only have to call `memcpy` once then free the array pointed to by `depthBuffer`. Unless you are just using the pointer. Then you have to think about who has to delete that float array, because it was created with `new`.

I think the better option is to use the method with this signature: `int GetZbufferData( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, vtkFloatArray* z )`

In python that looks likes this:

```
import vtk
# create render pipeline (not shown)
# define image bounds (not shown)
vfa = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
ib = image_bounds
render_window.GetZbufferData(ib[0], ib[1], ib[2], ib[3], vfa)
```

Major benefit is that the pointer for the `vtkFloatArray` gets handed straight to `glReadPixels`. Also, vtk will take of garbage collection of the `vtkFloatArray` if you create it with `vtkSmartPointer` (not needed in Python)

My python implementation is running at about 150Hz on a single pass. On a 640x480 render window.

edit: Running at 150Hz

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did the thing you suggested (updated the post) but the result is the same. I also found that PBO (pixel buffer object) should be used, would you be able to help with that?